# powershell - adding a string to output fill name is throwing an error

Tags: powershell, output

I have this function where I want the output file name should be same as the filename with "_new.log" added to the end. This is my script. it does not work.

```
Function IIS-CleanUp1($file)
{
Get-Content $file | ? { $_ -match $control -and $_ -notmatch '^\#'} | Out-File $file + "_new.log"
}

IIS-CleanUp1 "u_ex130801.log"
```

It throws the following error:

```
Out-File : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Encoding'. The argument "+" does not belong to the set "unicode,utf7,
utf8,utf32,ascii,bigendianunicode,default,oem" specified by the ValidateSet attribute. Supply an argument that is in th
e set and then try the command again.
At C:\ShiyamTemp\IIS_CCHECK_AUG\IIS.ps1:3 char:79
+ Get-Content $file | ? { $_ -match $control -and $_ -notmatch '^\#'} | Out-File <<<<  $file + "_new.log"
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Out-File], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand
```

Any help is much appreciated:

- T

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is taking the `+` as the second argument to `Out-File`, which is the `Encoding` and that is why see the above error. Try something like:

```
.. | Out-File $($file + "_new.log")
```

You might have to handle file name and extension better as follows:

```
$f = get-item $file
$newpath = join-path $f.directoryname $($f.basename + "_new" + $f.extension) 
get-content $f | ... | out-file $newpath
```

Comment: Thanks. It fixed the issue. But it says u_ex130801.log_new.log. It is doing what the code is asking it to do. How can I make it say u_ex130801_new.log

Comment: @user1666952 - What is `$file`? See updated answer for an approach.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks again. Worked like a charm